# How do I create a variable to keep track of my html select option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This code switches between 5 different images and works fine.  What I need is a variable to track what option I selected.  I can't use the value option as I use that for the image path, I cant do any string manipulation, as I need the exact value of the value option to display image on the current page.  I need another variable to pass to a PHP page which holds the table field name to a sql table that has fields image_1, image_2, image_3, image_4 or image_5.  In short, if the option "Image 1" is selected, I need a variable to tell it to write path to field "image_1" in my sql table. If "image 2" is selected it would write to field "image_2" ect...

```
<select id="selected_image" name="selected_image" onchange="
$(\'#imageToSwap\').attr(\'src\', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">

<option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_1 . ' " selected>Image 1</option>
<option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_2 . ' ">Image 2</option>
<option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_3 . ' ">Image 3</option>
<option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_4 . ' ">Image 4</option>
<option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_5 . ' ">Image 5</option>
</select>

<img id="imageToSwap" class="profile" src="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image . ' ">
```

Added the Jquery below

```
$( "option" ).click(function() {
var index = $( "option" ).index( this );
$( "span" ).text( "Image Selected #" + (index+1));
});
```

Comment: What about `$_POST['selected_image']`

Comment: Yes, that holds my path such as /mywebsite/images/myimage.jpg and works fine.  But i need to write value of $_POST['selected_image'] to a sql table in fields  image_1, image_2 ect.  I need a variable to track what field I will write to in my table

Answer (score 2):

That's not how html should work. The `value` attribute is designed to contain the value you want to pass in the submit event, so it should contain a unique identifier that allows you to retrieve all the details server-side, when you process the $_POST array.

Said this, if you still want to pass two values, possible workarounds are:

- Set the value you want to pass into a `class` attribute and retrieve it with `$(this).attr("class")`. Then you have to add it manually to the ajax request parameters (if you're using ajax)*.
- Get the [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/) of the selected element and pass it instead of `image_1, image_2 etc.`. Still, you need to include it in the $POST array manually*.
- Add a disabled hidden input after every options. The hidden input contains the value you want to pass. When you select an image, disable all the inputs and enable just the corrensponding one `$(this).next().prop('disabled', false);` so just this one will be included in the $POST array.

But you really should rethink *why* complicate simple things.

---

*To add manually a value to an HTTP request, you can addd an hidden input in the form and set its value with jquery after a click event. Otherwise if you're using ajax, you add it to the request data.

Comment: Hey T30, I found example in that index link that should work for me.  Thanks.  I will update post later with my results.

Comment: $( "option" ).click(function() {
    // `this` is the DOM element that was clicked
    var index = $( "option" ).index( this );
   $( "span" ).text( "Image Selected #" + (index+1));
   });

Comment: Just an hint: Instead of setting it as a span text, set it as a value of an hidden input, so you don't have to add it manually to the post request.

Comment: Added some jquery and now have the index variable assigned to each option.  I can use the index variable on my php page to decide which field to write to in my table.  Thanks for leading me down the correct path T30.  I have added the new jquery above

Answer (score 0):

Give each option a `name` tag then you can see the value via the `$_POST['name']`.
for example `<option name="image_1"....>` would be `$_POST['image_1']` etc

Comment: If there's just this input in the form, this is a good solution. Server-side you can write something like `"insert into <table>(".array_keys[$_POST][0]".) values(".array_values[$_POST][0].")"`

Answer (score 0):

This works great, thanks for everyones input

```
<span>Click a option!</span>

<select id="selected_image" name="selected_image" onchange="
$(\'#imageToSwap\').attr(\'src\',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">

<option name="image_1" value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image . ' " selected>Image 1</option>
<option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_2 . ' ">Image 2</option>
<option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_3 . ' ">Image 3</option>
<option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_4 . ' ">Image 4</option>
<option value="' .$shop_name_pdo . '/images/' . $p_image_5 . ' ">Image 5</option>
</select>

<script>
$( "option" ).click(function() {
// `this` is the DOM element that was clicked
var index = $( "option" ).index( this );
$( "span" ).text( "Image Selected #" + (index+1));
});
</script>
```